# Switching A DataSource Based On A User

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc

Hi I'm working on a Spring MVC project.
My first db (which is the masterdb) contains details of databases like
[image]

First my application goes through the master db and checks for correct username and password. If it is matching, it will choose the appropriate db and switch the data source of the application. From then on, the app will choose that database only.
I tried to refer the master db and my problem is that I cannot switch to a specific database. There are many school db's and details of each school db is stored inside master db .

**login controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login-auth.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginAuth(final Login userAccount,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            HttpSession session, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
            SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        //DataSource dataSource = null;
        log.info(userAccount.getUserName());
        Login login=loginService.findLoginByUserName(userAccount.getUserName());
        if(login==null){
            return null;
        }
        //data source switching will be done here
        return "school-admin/index";
    }
```

**initial data source config**

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login_db" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Why not a multi tenant database? Give it a try. I think it would be better to have just one maintenance point. The designe will have to change a bit of course but the improvements will be lot better.

Comment: we can not predict the no of school databases. does it work in multi tenant database?

Comment: Is the web application single user one? If so, you can go with this approach. But for multi-user, you would need to maintain the database connection at session level and not at application.

Comment: it is a multi user app. do you have any simple working app for study purpose.

Comment: AbstractRoutingDataSource might help you. Read http://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/

Comment: i walk through the above link , but they are using static dbs. but in my case i want dynamic dbs.

Comment: @jijeshvu07 yes it does. take a look at this article from oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89240 which will be the same for others databases.

Comment: do you have any working samples?